# Python's Popen in Windows both succeeds and fails at the same thing

Tags: python, windows

```
LYX_EXE = r'"c:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\bin\LyX2.3.exe"'
process = subprocess.Popen(LYX_EXE)
```

This works - the program loads.

```
LYX_EXE = r'"c:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\bin\LyX2.3.exe"'
process = subprocess.Popen([LYX_EXE])
```

This fails: I get "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied".

What did I do wrong? I need the second call type since I want to use parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the second call type you have to avoid the quoting (Since it's already in a list, the executable and arguments are already separated):

```
LYX_EXE = r"c:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\bin\LyX2.3.exe"
process = subprocess.Popen([LYX_EXE])
```

See also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence

Comment: To clarify, on Windows an args list gets joined back into a command line, which gets passed to WinAPI `CreateProcess`. subprocess uses the VC++ `argv` and WinAPI `CommandLineToArgvW` rules, which are how most programs consume their command line, with notable exceptions such as the CMD shell.